# How to define it as a macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

```
case MAP_KEY3:
case MAP_KEY4:
case MAP_KEY5:
case MAP_KEY6:
    break;
default:
    LampShow(LampID, 0);
    LampShow(LampID, 2);
    LampShow(LampID, 0);
    break;
```

I want to make a MARCO of above code so that I can use it anywhere repeatedly. But how to do?
It is for C language.

If I do it like below:

```
#define AAA /
    case MAP_KEY3:  /
    case MAP_KEY4:  /
    case MAP_KEY5:  /
    case MAP_KEY6:  /
        break;      /
    default:        /
        LampShow(LampID, 0);   /
        LampShow(LampID, 2);   /
        LampShow(LampID, 0);   /
        break;
```

Then I will got this error:

```
34: syntax error before `case'
```

line 34 is `case MAP_KEY3:  /`

Comment: Why not simply put it in a function and make it a inline function? Why do you think macro is better than an inline function in this case? With macro you will lose all the type safety, which should be a concern since you are calling some function eventually.

Comment: Just do it. What's preventing you?

Comment: That will need to define the interface of the function and looks a little bit complex. MACRO replacement will be easier.

Comment: @AlokSave It seems like the OP wants that partial switch to be a macro. It won't work as a function since it won't compile as-is.

Comment: @TomXue You're using the wrong slash. You need the backslash instead of the forward slash.

Comment: I found it, thank you very much!

Comment: @Mysticial The point is, the urge to write an icky macro for part of a switch statement is created by muddy thinking and obfuscated program design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define EVIL_MACRO \
case MAP_KEY3: \
case MAP_KEY4: \
case MAP_KEY5: \
case MAP_KEY6: \
    break; \
default: \
    LampShow(LampID, 0); \
    LampShow(LampID, 2); \
    LampShow(LampID, 0); \
    break;
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to make a MARCO of above code so that I can use it anywhere repeatedly

That's what functions are for.